# How to make a MariaDB SSH Connection in Katalon Studio?

Tags: mysql, ssh, mariadb, katalon-studio

My host does not allow direct database access and so I need to SSH into the MariaDB instance.

Has anyone had success with this approach in Katalon Studio?

The recommended JDBC connection will not suffice

```
@Keyword
def connectDB(String url, String dbname, String port, String username, String password){

    //Load driver class for your specific database type

    String conn = "jdbc:mysql://" + url + ":" + port + "/" + dbname

    //Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")

    //String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dataFile

    if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){

        connection.close()

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there is something specific to MariaDB. What happens when you try the above code?

Comment: I've edited your code, in order to format `@keyword` in the snippet, and added a closing `}` at the end.

Comment: Might be helpful https://forum.katalon.com/t/unable-to-connect-to-memsql-using-katalon-7-3-0/42261/12